# How to check if variable is string with python 2 and 3 compatibility

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm aware that I can use: `isinstance(x, str)` in python-3.x but I need to check if something is a string in python-2.x as well. Will `isinstance(x, str)` work as expected in python-2.x? Or will I need to check the version and use `isinstance(x, basestr)`?

Specifically, in python-2.x:

```
>>>isinstance(u"test", str)
False
```

and python-3.x does not have `u"foo"`

Comment: u"" syntax for Unicode literals is reintroduced in Python 3.3

Comment: Odd. I get

 
```
>>> isinstance(u"test", basestring)
True
```


on Python 2.7.16

Answer (score 223, accepted):

If you're writing 2.x-and-3.x-compatible code, you'll probably want to use [six](http://packages.python.org/six/#six.string_types):

```
from six import string_types
isinstance(s, string_types)
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confuse about the following result.
 
`>>> isinstance(u"foo", string_types)`

`True`

`>>> isinstance(u"foo".encode("utf-8"), string_types)`

`True`

I was expecting isinstance(u"foo", string_types) return false.

Comment: @Chandler.Huang this question is about identifying `str` and `unicode` on Python 2, or `str` on Python 3. If you don't want `unicode` to count on Python 2, just use `str`.

Comment: @ecatmur woops, thanks! deleted it, so noone gets confused

Comment: you can also use it from `future` package instead of `six`: `from future.utils import string_types`

Answer (score 128):

The most terse approach I've found without relying on packages like six, is:

```
try:
  basestring
except NameError:
  basestring = str
```

then, assuming you've been checking for strings in Python 2 in the most generic manner,

```
isinstance(s, basestring)
```

will now also work for Python 3+.

Comment: For py3, `basestring = (str, bytes)` from `requests/compat.py`

Comment: Nice, but why? It would be nice if Python3 would be backward-compatible here. Above solutions works. Would be even better, if there would be no need for it.

Comment: To satisfy both py2 &3 support and mypy, I ended up with `if not hasattr(__builtins__, "basestring"): basestring = (str, bytes)`

Answer (score 41):

What about this, works in all cases?

```
isinstance(x, ("".__class__, u"".__class__))
```

Comment: @holdenweb: No and yes - a nifty "only impacts where needed" hack I think.

Comment: The reason why I like this answer is that it is friendly with migrating from python2 to 3.

Comment: I also went with this option, wrapping it in a helper function, so it only appears once, and there's a place in the docstring to credit Fil.

Comment: Neat, and I was using it myself, until I realized that I also have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` active.  Now I'm going with: `isinstance(val, (str, u"".__class__))`

Comment: Not _quite_ all cases, in python 3 this is just unicode strings twice.  If you want to include byte strings and unicode strings in both python versions, the first one also needs a prefix: `(b''.__class__, u''.__class__)`, and if you only want unicode strings then just `u''.__class__` is sufficient.  Anyway, I needed this style because I also needed to detect byte strings and six's `string_types` didn't work.

Answer (score 19):

This is @Lev Levitsky's answer, re-written a bit.

```
try:
    isinstance("", basestring)
    def isstr(s):
        return isinstance(s, basestring)
except NameError:
    def isstr(s):
        return isinstance(s, str)
```

The `try`/`except` test is done once, and then defines a function that always works and is as fast as possible.

EDIT: Actually, we don't even need to call `isinstance()`; we just need to evaluate `basestring` and see if we get a `NameError`:

```
try:
    basestring  # attempt to evaluate basestring
    def isstr(s):
        return isinstance(s, basestring)
except NameError:
    def isstr(s):
        return isinstance(s, str)
```

I think it is easier to follow with the call to `isinstance()`, though.

Comment: `isinstance("", basestring)` is what I meant by "calling". Anyway, +1.

Comment: Python is a very dynamic language, and I don't think it looks bad at all to have a test like that.  This is a useful technique for figuring something out one time, and based on that, setting up a function that will always be correct.  Thanks for the +1.

Comment: I'd write it as: `try: string_types = basestring except NameError: string_types = str`

Answer (score 11):

The [`future` library](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#unicode) adds (to Python 2) **compatible names**, so you can **continue writing Python 3**. You can simple do the following:

```
from builtins import str
isinstance(x, str)
```

---

**To install it**, just execute `pip install future`.

As a *caveat*, it only support `python>=2.6`,`>=3.3`, but it is more modern than `six`, which is only [recommended if using `python 2.5`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#drop-support-for-python-2-6-and-older)

Comment: `from builtins import str; isinstance('foo', str)` returns False in python 2.7

Comment: This will not work with Python 2 string literals.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe use a workaround like

```
def isstr(s):
    try:
        return isinstance(s, basestring)
    except NameError:
        return isinstance(s, str)
```

Comment: Sorry to bug you but `isinstance(u'hello', basestr)` yields `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for me with Python 3.2.3 under Window 7 .. any idea why this would be? It doesn't seem to like the `u` - I get this error with `str` and `basestr`

Comment: @Levon No problem :) That's because [Python3 doesn't have that syntax](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), as `str` in Python3 is by definition Unicode. Accordingly, there's no `basestring` type, hence the `NameError` that is caught in my snippet.

Comment: It does have that syntax as a noop now. in 3.3

Comment: I would suggest doing the `try`/`except` test a single time, and based on the results of that single test, you define `isstr()` correctly.  There is no need to incur the overhead of an exception for every call to `isstr()`.

Comment: @Ranman is right about Python 3.3, here's a link to [the PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/).

Comment: @steveha Good point, but that would kinda look bad, as one would have to actually call the function once for the exception to be raised.

Comment: @LevLevitsky, it is not necessary to call the function to test which way to define the function.  Okay, I'll post this as an answer since code looks bad in a comment.

Comment: Levon said it raised a Syntax error, not a NameError. It does that because it's `basestring` and not `basestr`

Answer (score 8):

You can get the class of an object by calling `object.__class__`, so in order to check if object is the default string type:

```
    isinstance(object,"".__class__)
```

And You can place the following in the top of Your code so that strings enclosed by quotes are in unicode in python 2:

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Comment: I this solution quite a bit.  I found it can be useful to define str = "".__class__, which now allows isinstance(object, str) to be written normally, and also ensures that str(object) will return a unicode string in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: This doesn't work when parsing XML: `some_element.text` is a 'str' but the compare with 'unicode' would fail

Comment: Does't work with unicode string on python 2: isinstance(u'XXX', ''.__class__) == False

Answer (score 1):

You can try this at the beginning of your code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
if sys.version[0] == "2":
    py3 = False
else:
    py3 = True
if py3: 
    basstring = str
else:
    basstring = basestring
```

and later in the code:

```
anystring = "test"
# anystring = 1
if isinstance(anystring, basstring):
    print("This is a string")
else:
    print("No string")
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful! In python 2, `str` and `bytes` are essentially the same. This can cause a bug if you are trying to distinguish between the two.

```
>>> size = 5    
>>> byte_arr = bytes(size)
>>> isinstance(byte_arr, bytes)
True
>>> isinstance(byte_arr, str)
True
```

Answer (score -5):

type(string) == str

returns true if its a string, and false if not

Comment: Not true for Python 2, where `string` is a unicode string