# wording assert function difficulty in python

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a code and the only problem I have is the assert function syntax. For the function `great(s,b)`, `b` has to be in range `(2,37)` and `s` has to be a string. At the same time I need to assert that `s` contain only digits `0-9`, letters `a-z`, and the `.` (dot).

```
def great(s,b):
       assert b in range(2,37) and type(s)==str
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether b is integer in range from `2` to `37` inclusively:

```
assert isinstance(b, int) and 2 <= b <= 37
```

`s` being a string ([for python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301138/how-to-check-if-variable-is-string-with-python-2-and-3-compatibility))

```
assert isinstance(s, str)
```

For checking against fixed number of symbols, one can use [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html):

```
import re
allowed_re = re.compile('^[0-9a-z.]*$')
assert allowed_re.match(s)
```

Comment: i dont understand the last part. what is re? isnt there an easier way?

Comment: @user2751595 yes, there are others, I just don't have py3 at hand and can't check exact syntax of `translate` for example.

Answer (score -1):

the error info needed, assertion link, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/assertions_in_python.htm

```
def great(s,b):
        assert ((b in range(2,37)) and (type(s)==str)), "error happens"
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. Please read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/simple_stmts.html).