# Equivalent to unicode() function that works with both Python 2.7 and 3.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I'm trying to adapt some old code to make it usable with both Python 2 and 3. I'm using the [six package](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) for this task.

If I have `u'abc'` in 2.7, I can use the [six.u()](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.u) function and replace it with `six.u('abc')` to make it work in both 2.7 and 3.x.

How do I do something similar for:

- `unicode(value, errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8')`

There is no `unicode` function in 3.x and I can't just replace it with `str` because that will change the meaning in 2.7.

- `if isinstance(value, basestring): # do something`

There is no `basestring` in 3.x and again I can't just replace it with `str` without changing the meaning.

Of course, I can use the [py2/3 checks](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#package-contents) with `six.PY2` or `six.PY3` to run one of two versions but is there a better way?

Comment: You can use `u'string'` syntax in Python 3.3+.

Comment: For the latter, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11301138/3001761

Comment: I think that it's difficult to answer this question generally ... In principle, you'd use `unicode` in python2.x to coerce something (presumably a `str`) into `unicode`.  On python3.x, the analogy would be coercing _bytes_ into `str` -- And for that, you usually just `.decode` the bytes I think...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of the question, you can replace `if isinstance(value, basestring):` with `six.string_types`:

```
import six
if isinstance(value, six.string_types):
    pass
```

To answer the first part, I would first recommend putting this at the top of your code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

This will make all your Python2 `str` literals become `unicode` which will be a big first step in compatibility.

Second, if you really need some sort of compatibility conversion function, try this:

```
def py23_str(value):
    try:  # Python 2
        return unicode(value, errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8')
    except NameError:  # Python 3
        try:
            return str(value, errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8')
        except TypeError:  # Wasn't a bytes object, no need to decode
            return str(value)
```

I will say that I have written a few Python2/3 compatible libraries, and I have *never* needed to do this. Adding `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of the code and calling `.decode` on `bytes` (or `str` in Python2) objects when they are created (i.e. reading from file in `'rb'` mode) is all that I have needed so far.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I don't have control over what value can be. Suppose `value = 'xyz'`. In 2.7, `unicode(value, errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8')` will work just fine but in 3.x, the same thing with `str(value, errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8')` will produce `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`.

Comment: Have you tried `from __future__ import unicode_literals`?  That may help make it so you do not need to do this explicit decoding.